# Why is this zip file unable to open?

Tags: zip

I'm trying to unzip a zip file which contains a video... right  away it says:

> 7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18 p7zip
>   Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
>
> Error: /home/cyberproxy/Downloads/Floating1a.zip: Can not open file as
>   archive
>
> Errors: 1

Unzips on my Android, unzips on my Windows desktop, unzips on my mother's iOS device with unzipper app.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the command you used to open the file?

Comment: I right clicked "Extract Here."

Comment: Does the file unzip on another system?

It seems like you may have a corrupt file.

Comment: Unzips on my Android, unzips on my Windows desktop, unzips on my mother's iOS device with unzipper app.

Comment: Using Ubuntu now

Comment: Would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: When comments ask for clarification, always [edit] that clarification into the answer, then comment (with `@name` to the person) to say that you have done so. Comments are often unread, and may be deleted. Also, in general, it's better for a question to be self-contained, rather than relying on comments.

Comment: hm, can `p7zip` handle a .zip file? shouldn't you be using `unzip`? or is it a `7zip` file with a .zip extension?

Comment: @roadmr Yes this is compatible. From the man page of 7z: _"7-Zip is a file archiver supporting 7z (that implements LZMA compression algorithm featuring very high compression ratio), LZMA2, XZ, ZIP, Zip64, CAB, RAR (it was removed due a non-free license), ARJ, GZIP, BZIP2, TAR, CPIO, RPM, ISO, most filesystem images  and  DEB  formats.   Compression ratio in the new 7z format is 30-50% better than ratio in ZIP format. 7z uses plugins to handle archives, so it might be slightly slower than 7za(1) but can handle more archive formats."_

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading p7zip-full from the standard repository.

"p7zip-full provides utilities to pack and unpack 7z archives within
a shell or using a GUI (such as Ark, File Roller or Nautilus)."

EDIT:  It seems that newer versions of File Roller can open 7Z files automatically, according to the installation notes.

Comment: Please add instructions on how to use it (less experienced users who wouldn't have a clue what to type).

Comment: Once installed, "p7zip-full provides utilities to pack and unpack 7z archives within a shell or using a GUI (such as Ark, File Roller or Nautilus)."  IE, It will work just like normal zip, no extra commands required.

Comment: It says it's already been installed. Weird.

Comment: In that case, are you sure that the copy on Ubuntu is *exactly* the same as the one you can open successfully?  Perhaps it got corrupted.  Or, check permissions to make sure you have permissions (check owner and permissions in properties).

Comment: Yup! Same copy [Bluetooth transfer]. Nothing seems off about the permission. I just installed Kubuntu and it opened the zip instantly -- although nothing was in it, it still unzipped.

Comment: nothing was in it? Why is that?  If nothing is in it, then what's the point?  And if something *is* in it, then how can you say Kubuntu unzipped it?  Also, how did you verify that the copy is the same?  Just because it's a Bluetooth transfer doesn't make it the same - there could have been an error, and one little error on a compressed file is enough.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that the archive is not properly formatted as such. The unzip program doesn't think that it's a valid zip file.

Try opening a terminal (search for it in your programs menu). For the purposes of this demonstration, I'm going to assume it's in your `downloads` folder.

Once you've opened the terminal do the following:

1. Change directory to the `downloads` folder.

   `cd ~/Downloads`
2. Unzip the file using the command-line tool, unzip

   `unzip Floating1a.zip`

This should put it into a folder (or give you a zip-bomb in the current directory) of everything that's in it. If this fails, it is almost guaranteed to be a problem with the file, not the unzip program.

Comment: It still didn't work -- what I don't understand is how an Android device can open it but a real Linux machine can't. I'm baffled.

Comment: 7z format is a newer format, and not a standard zip format.  It is probably a licensing issue, but the required addon is freely available from the Ubuntu repository, as are other non-standard formats.

Comment: But that still doesn't explain why Android can do it. Although I understand you,

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not really zipped at all and the other sources are recognizing this and opening it as it should be opened (in a media player)? try opening it with VLC or whatever program you have installed for media.

Comment: On further investigation, I see that on my system (xubuntu), file-roller has the ability to open 7z files.  But the previous suggestion might also be good.  BTW, Android != Linux; it is only built on parts of the Linux Kernel.  I doubt that Linux includes this ability anyway, though.

Comment: I know that Android is Linux, that's why it's surprising Android has more power than "Ubuntu" Linux. In various respects like this one. I'll try Xubuntu.

Comment: Xubuntu won't make a difference, I don't think, because it uses File Roller, same as Ubuntu.  I was saying Android is *not* Linux; technically, Ubuntu really isn't either.  Both use a version of the Linux Kernel, but the kernel is not an app or a GUI, it is just used by apps and guis (and distros).