# Can't extract zip file Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, zip, unzip

For example,I created a simple zip file (inside I have the sentence: hello world!) in desktop. I want to unzip it, but nothing happens. I also installed (zip unzip) with this command: `sudo apt install zip unzip`, but it says that I have already have the newest versions of these installed.

Here is the error I get in the terminal:

[image: Here is the error I get in the terminal]

Comment: "Can't extract file.zip" Care to show to us what's the error you see?

Comment: There was an error while extracting "file.zip"

Comment: Please don't post additional information as answers. This is not a forum. [edit] your question instead.

Comment: There may be two reasons: 1) The archive is really corrupt; 2) File names may have non-ascii characters. The second can be fixed. Can you give a link to that file?

Comment: Hey Nick, please use the [edit button](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1228239/edit) to append answers to your question as opposed to making multiple answers. Have a look at some other questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/790929/does-ubuntu-come-with-a-zip-file-extracter?rq=1 / https://askubuntu.com/questions/520546/how-to-extract-a-zip-file-to-a-specific-folder?rq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/482849/why-is-this-zip-file-unable-to-open?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unzip error "End-of-central-directory signature not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54904/unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

First, in the terminal use the `cd` command to change to the location you want. An example being `cd /home/nick/Downloads`. From here, verify that the file exists using `ls -la | grep .zip` to ensure you're in the right location.

From here, if you want to unzip to the current location, just run:

```
unzip file.zip
```

Comment: Hey @Nick_Gkoutzas, the error stipulates that the zip file has no content, or `Zip` cannot read the file. A return of `ls -la` might give you file size. If corrupted, I'd suggest a redownload of the file.

Comment: I changed this zip file to tar file and I I will try to untar it .if that doesn't work ,I will redownload the file

Comment: Hey Nick, in your other post it states the file seems corrupt. Try again with the download, otherwise perhaps try to use [something like 7Zip](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/install-7zip-ubuntu-linux-command-line.html) to see if this is a compression issue.

Answer (score 0):

A better question is "How did you create the zip file?"
If you made it in an editor, it's not "really" a zip archive and unzip won't work. If you want the contents, use `cat hello.zip`.
To *properly* create a zip file, you can use, `zip filename.zip filename`.